# Git terminal goes crazy whenever I revise code or layout on android studio

Tags: android, git, mobile, github

As the title states I am making an app with android studio. I recently installed git as well in order to interface with GitHub. For some reason whenever I change the layout on the layout editor, or type more than 3 characters of code the git terminal opens up multiple windows, then they disappear, and I get no errors of any kind. It repeats indefinitely and I am really unable to get any work done because of it. Has anyone seen anything like this before and if so I would love any help I could get. Thank you! I tried to make this as detailed as possible hopefully it isn't too broad.

Comment: Are you using Git from the terminal entirely, or are you using a Git plugin with android studio?

Comment: I think just the terminal, I never added a plugin as far as I can remeber. But i also downloaded github desktop if that matters

Comment: Ok. If you navigate to your repository directory through the terminal and type `git status`, what is the output?